# Swift: Detect when buy alert displays for in-app purchases

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase, alert

I have code similar to a tutorial for in-app purchases shown here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/122144/in-app-purchase-tutorial

**Edit:** This would not only need to work for the Buy alert, but also the alert window that comes up if the user needs to put in their Username and password.

Since it takes some time for the Buy alert to show up, I put a "please wait" screen up and disabled my buttons. The problem is that I don't know how to detect the Buy alert, or where in this code it's called to show up so that I can remove the "please wait" screen at the correct time.

For instance, I call purchaseMyProduct, but I see nothing inside that function that makes that popup display, or nothing called at the same time the popup displays. My only guess is that it adds to the SKPaymentQueue, and then it's up to the OS to show the Buy popup whenever it's ready to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't* put up a "please wait" screen. The interchange with the app store happens outside your process. You can't detect it, and you don't need to. When the user taps *your* Buy button, just dismiss *your* Buy interface, stick your product onto the queue, and have your app go back to a normal quiescent state. The next voice you'll hear, if any, will be your SKPaymentTransactionObserver telling you that the user did in fact make the purchase.

Comment: It's too bad it works that way, and kind of messy. I really don't want the user poking around until the transaction failed, cancels or goes through. I checked some other apps with in app purchases, and they work like you said, but it's still unbelievable to me.